# Unable to Create Policy for AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr, aws-policies

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/yyy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Command I try to use is:

```
aws ecr set-repository-policy --repository-name yyy --policy-text file://ecr-policy.json
```

If I do `ls` in my linux machine I can see this `ecr-policy.json` in same folder where I run this command.

I want to grant access to myself.

I am always getting error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the SetRepositoryPolicy operation: Invalid parameter at 'PolicyText' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid repository policy provided'

I checked my AWS ARN and it ends with `root`.

Comment: You want grant another account or users in an account to access your ECR?

Comment: i want to grant access to myself.

Comment: None of the [Private repository policy examples - Amazon ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html) have `Resource` field -- could that be the cause? Also, do you have an actual IAM User called `root`, or are you wanting to grant the access to the "Root User" of your AWS Account?

Comment: 'Root User' of AWS account.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you're right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try resource in a format:

```
arn:${Partition}:ecr:${Region}:${Account}:repository/${Repository-name}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html

Answer (score 3):

`i want to grant access to myself.`

You don't need a resource section because this statement will be attached to a specific repository. Try add the following statement at Console > ECR > **Repositories** > [Select a repo on the `Images` table] > **Permissions**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account #>:user/<your IAM user name>",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account #>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE:** Replace <account #> with your AWS account ID.

Comment: API error
Invalid parameter at 'PolicyText' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid registry policy provided'

Comment: Checkout the updated answer. Do you get the error when you try on the console `Console > ECR > Repositories > Permissions`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Resource` in Policy json file

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you can set on AWS Console

1. Go to `Amazon ECR > Repositories`
2. Create Repository
3. Click what your create Repository
4. and go to `permissions` tab
5. Edit permissions -> Input the above json file

[image]